# Liferay: Display Inbuilt User Registration in a jsp

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-aui

How to display default user registration or User Creation form in Portlet/Jsp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to build the render-url that renders the jsp.

Take a look at [`/portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/login/navigation/create_account.jsp`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/login/navigation/create_account.jsp#L33) as to how the URL is created.

You just need to have this method call `PortalUtil.getCreateAccountURL(request, themeDisplay)`.

so your JSP code might look something like this:

```
<a href=<%=PortalUtil.getCreateAccountURL(request, themeDisplay)%>> Create Account </a>
```

<sub>**Note:** I have not tried this, but it should more or less work.</sub>